# Improving the accuracy of the bounding box detection of TextRecognize

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks, ocr

My problem concerns the text position detection in a scan. My goal is to find the bounding boxes of the text.

```
img = Import@"1.png";
res = TextRecognize[img, "Line", "BoundingBox"];
HighlightImage[img, {"Boundary", res}]
```

[source image is here, there are 7 images](https://github.com/HyperGroups/Mathematica/blob/master/Questions/Q%40TextRecognize/data.statistical_learning_method/1.png) or [here is the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvuZD.png)

As you can see in the following picture, the result is not good enough. How can I make all the bounding boxes accurate?

[image: result]

Comment: You should consider setting the `Language->"Chinese"` and taking a look at `RecognitionPrior`.

Comment: @Carl In Text Detection not Recognize, it seems, Language->"Chinese" is useless, I've tried that

Comment: I think TextRecognize just uses [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) and thus it is pretty limited. Try to just use Tesseract and tweak it. If you can do that, then you can try to tweak options of TextRecognize. And if you can't, and you think it is a bug in Tesseract, you can send a bug report to them. But most probably they just say it is not a bug, but a feature (happened to me back in [2016](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/305))